# Post on (not edit) a different page on your tumblr

Tags: tumblr, posts

How do I make posts on a new page on my tumblr? For instance, my home page is just omyn.tumblr.com, where all my normal reblogs go. But I also have a page there with the URL: omyn.tumblr.com/journey

How do I make a post that posts to that page only? I don't really care if it goes on my home page at the same time it goes on my "/journey" page, so long as it at least shows up there.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to achieve this, both rely on Tumblr Pages.

**One Post Only - Standard Layout**

To show only one post, pick standard layout:

1. Add a page (via the customize screen), and pick standard layout.
2. Set the `url` to `journey`.
3. Add content to the page body.

The standard layout, use the *Text Post Type*, and the page body will render as if it was a *Text Post*.

**Multiple Posts - Redirect**

To show multiple posts, pick redirect:

1. Any post you want to show on your *journey* page, tag with `journey`.
2. `omyn.tumblr.com/tagged/journey` will display posts tagged `journey`.
3. Add a page (via the customize screen), and pick redirect.
4. Set the `url` to `journey` and redirect to `omyn.tumblr.com/tagged/journey`.
5. `omyn.tumblr.com/journey` will now show posts tagged `journey`.

These posts will still show up on the `Index Page`. It is possible to hide them using `CSS` or `Javascript`.

Comment: @displayname if the solution worked, I presume your question would be closed as a duplicate of this?

Comment: No, why? My question is about something completely different actually ^^

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought the question you asked was solved by this answer.